# insertion in binary search tree (C++)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm new to data structure.
I'm making a C++ program for insertion of an element in binary search tree .
The program compiles without any error but when I'm running the program , after giving the first input n , the program stops working.
Kindly help me in making this program work properly.

My code follows up as:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node *root=NULL ,*par=NULL ,*pos=NULL,*save=NULL , *ptr=NULL ;
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    struct node* newnode= (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->right=NULL; 
    newnode->left=NULL;
    return newnode;
}

void findpos(int data)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        par=NULL,pos=NULL;
        return;
    }

    if(root->data==data)
    {
        par=NULL , pos=root;
        return;
    }

    if(data<root->data)
    {
        save=root; ptr=root->left; 
    }
    else{
        save=root; ptr=root->right;
    }
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->data==data)
        {
            par=save; pos=ptr;
            return;
        }
        if(data<ptr->data)
        {
            save=ptr;
            ptr=ptr->left;
        }
        else{
            save=ptr;
            ptr=ptr->right;
        }
    }

    pos=NULL; par=save;
    return;
}


void insert(int data)
{
    findpos(data);
    if(pos!=NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    pos=newNode(data);
    if(data<par->data)
    par->left=pos;

    else
    par->right=pos;

    return;
}



  int main()
    {
    struct node *root=  newNode(4);
    root->left=newNode(3);
    root->left->left=newNode(2);
    root->right=newNode(6);

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    insert(n);
    cout<<pos->data;  //just trying to see if it works
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Declare variables whenever they are required and too many if else condition in function `findpos()`.

Comment: Only using `cin`/`cout` does not make this program C++

Comment: 1. Draw out the tree you wish to build on a piece of paper. 2. Run the program with the the debugger that came with your development environment. 3. Step through the program with the debugger until the code deviates from your expectations (ie doesn't look like the tree you drew in step 1). 4. Use the debugger to examine the program state to see why this happened. Possibly run multiple times to track the deviation back to the source.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need to specify `struct` every time you use it.  Are you positive you are using the C++ language and not C?

Comment: Instead of passing values through global variables, try returning them from functions or passing them as reference parameters.  Or, you could place the globals into a `class`, something like `class Binary_Search_Tree`.

Comment: BTW, in C++ memory is allocated through the `new` operator, because the `new` operator calls the object constructors; the `malloc` function does not call constructors.

Comment: You don't need to include `stdio.h`.  You are using `iostream` instead.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks! I figured out the conflicts. Well I wasn't using C++ , I was trying it in C , sorry for the wrong tag .

Answer (score 0):

The root pointer declared in the main() override the global root pointer. Then at the first findpos(), the root (global) is still NULL.
So, simply replace that code:

```
int main()
{
    struct node *root=  newNode(4);
    root->left=newNode(3);
    root->left->left=newNode(2);
    root->right=newNode(6);

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    insert(n);
    cout<<pos->data;  //just trying to see if it works
    return 0;
}
```

By this one:

```
int main()
{
    root=  newNode(4);
    root->left=newNode(3);
    root->left->left=newNode(2);
    root->right=newNode(6);

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    insert(n);
    cout<<pos->data;  //just trying to see if it works
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the main method so that it modifies root in global namespace; before you were declaring a new node called `root` localy within `main`.

```
int main() {
    //      struct node *root = newNode(4); // you made this root a member of main.
    // not a global member anymore. 

                    root = newNode(4); // use this

            // Populate some nodes
                    root->left=newNode(3);
                    root->left->left=newNode(2);
                    root->right=newNode(6);

                    /* tree so far:
                     *              4       
                     *             / \
                     *            3   6
                     *           /
                     *          2
                     */


                    int n;
                    cin >> n;
                    cout << "user input " << n << "\n";

                    insert(n);
                    cout << pos->data;  //just trying to see if it works

                    return 0;
}
```